# How to get notifications when a GAE cron job fails?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, stackdriver

I have an app which stores user data in GCP Datastore. Since this data is very important, I have made a cron job that is scheduled to export the data in the datastore using the instructions given here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export

Now, I want to get notifications when this cron job fails. I have tried the error reporting service from Stackdriver (https://console.cloud.google.com/errors?time=PT1H&filter&order=COUNT_DESC) to do this but it doesn't notify me when the job fails (yes, I intentionally made it fail to test it). The problem is Stackdriver regards cron job failure as mere warnings instead of errors. [Click here to see Stackdriver Logs Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggx6F.jpg).

How to get notifications when the cron job fails?

One way can be to get the Stackdriver Logs using stackdriver logging entries.list API (https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/) and then use it in a cron job which will notify me when any log has severity: warning or error or critical, but this process is very tedious.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to catch the exceptions and send yourself an email to get notified of a task failure.